# Estimating Debye and Fermi temperatures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

Given the  sketch of the behavior of the heat capacity against the temperature,

[image]

How do I estimate the Debye and Fermi temperatures?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the heat capacity of a solid is given by
$$C=\gamma\,T+A\,T^3 \quad . $$
If we plot $C/T$ as a function of $T^2$, we will see a straight line with slope $A$ and $y$-intercept $\gamma$. For the coefficients we know (under certain assumptions) that $\gamma \propto 1/T_{\mathrm{F}}$ and $A \propto (1/T_{\mathrm{D}})^3 $, where $T_{\mathrm{F}}$ and $T_{\mathrm{D}}$ denote the Fermi and Debye temperature, respectively. The proportionality constants are known (i.e. are fundamental constants). Thus, we simply read off the slope of the line and the intercept with the $y$-axis to extract the Fermi and Debye temperatures.

Most books on Solid State Physics will cover the corresponding derivations and explain under which conditions the above considerations are valid.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It helped me a lot.